# ConcurrentHashMap with parallel Streams to remove keys

Tags: java, java-8, concurrent-programming

I have following sequential code that removes entries from hash map using another list of keys. Map size can be 50-100k entries and Remove key list can be 2k - 10k. I am looking for solution using new java-8 streams...

```
    List<Long> removed = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (Long k : removelist) {
        if (null != map.remove(k)) {
            removed.add(k);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because a `HashMap` is not thread-safe, any sort of multi-threaded execution (streams or otherwise) would have to lock the map for each operation, meaning there'd be no benefit.  Using a `ConcurrentHashMap` avoids such locking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A kind of direct translation is

```
List<Long> removed = removeList.parallelStream()
        .map(key -> map.remove(key) != null ? key : null)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the `map` step maps from key to key if it could be removed, to `null` if not. `null`s are then filtered.

A bit shorter by directly filtering for those keys that can be removed:

```
    List<Long> removed = removeList.parallelStream()
        .filter(key -> map.remove(key) != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or via the key set's `remove` method which returns a `boolean` and can therefore be used directly as `Predicate`

```
    List<Long> removed = removeList.parallelStream()
            .filter(map.keySet()::remove)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: But you should always check whether it’s really faster than the ordinary sequential `removelist.retainAll(map.keySet()); map.keySet().removeAll(removelist);`

Comment: @Holger True. Though OPs explicit `for` loop should be faster than this one-liner since it's just 1 iteration and possibly over the smaller collection (in case `retainAll` iterates over the full keySet). Another point to consider: the [`concurrencyLevel` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap-int-float-int-) in the constructor of `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: `retainAll` never iterates over the parameter as that wouldn’t work. So in the worst case, it’s like the explicit loop, but usually, it can iterate faster and has lesser overhead as it operates in-place. Note that the concurrency level is completely irrelevant in Java 8 as `ConcurrentHashMap` does work different than in previous versions. That’s why the doc says “*The implementation may use this value as a sizing hint*”. In theory, there can be as much concurrency as there are entries without collisions. That’s why I say, you should always test and compare. Btw. I prefer your last variant.

Comment: @Holger, ha, really this concurrency level is practically useless parameter. I thought that CHM in Java-8 still uses segments, even though it was rewritten. New implementation is beyond my understanding for now...

Comment: @Holger Oh nice, locking individual tree nodes instead of locking segments. I din't know that :)